# Exim ACL to limit sender to send mail only to localdomain

Tags: email, exim, access-control-list

I'm currently using exim, and i need to limit a mail address to send mails only to local domain and deny mail to outgoing domains.

I think it could be like this :

```
deny  local_parts   = sender@localdomain
      domains       = !+local_domains
```

Can you please help me on that way ?

Thanks you very much guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the next rule at the beginning of acl_rcpt (or how you have called it)

```
deny condition = ${lookup{$sender_address}nwildlsearch{/path/to/the/local.user.list}{yes}}
       domains = !+local_domains
```

File `/path/to/the/local.user.list` should contain regexps one per line:

```
^john@domain\.tld
^.*_dpt@domain\.tld
^.*@inner\.domain\.tld
```

Comment: hey Kondybas, thanks for the answer :) I'll take a look and test it when i could in the next few days :) !

Comment: nwildlsearch only treats entries as regexps if they start with a circumflex `^`